# Conda - Creating an Anaconda environment for use with ArcGIS and creating environments with conflicting packages

Tags: python, anaconda, arcgis, environment, conda

I am new to Anaconda and conda.  I am trying to create a conda environment with conflicting packages to create an environment.  The purpose of this is to create an Anaconda environment for use with ArcGIS.  In the Anaconda Prompt, I type:

```
conda create -n arc1051 python=2.7.13 numpy=1.9.3 matplotlib=1.5.2 
scipy=0.17.0 pandas pyparsing xlrd xlwt console_shortcut
```

The error message that I receive is:

```
Solving environment:  failed

UnsatisfiableError:  The following specifications were found to be in 
conflict:
    - numpy=1.9.3
    - scipy=0.17.0 -> numpy=1.11
```

I think that I need all these packages in one environment, but it appears that I need to update numpy to 1.11 to work in an environment with scipy 0.17.0.  Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need numpy 1.9.3 specifically? I suppose you might be able to build scipy yourself, if it supports a numpy that old, but why do you need to?

Comment: I assume that I need numpy 1.9.3, because I am trying to create an Arc environment, and my current version of Arc uses numpy 1.9.3.  If you are interested, these are the instructions that I am following:  https://my.usgs.gov/confluence/display/EGIS/Using+Anaconda+modules+from+the+ESRI+python+environment

Comment: Ran into same issue and arbitrarily dropped the matplotlib explicit version when creating the environment. so numpy=1.9.3 and matplotlib=2.2.2. Is working for me thusfar.